# NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, nosuchelementexception

```
from selenium import webdriver

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

name = input('enter the name of user:')
msg = input('enter your message:')
count = int(input("enter the count:"))
user = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2lMWa')
user.click()
for i in range(count):
    msg_box.send_keys(msg)
    time.sleep(2)
    button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"tvf2evcx oq44ahr5 lb5m6g5c svlsagor p2rjqpw5 epia9gcq")
    button.click()
```

This is a sample code I took from github for whatsapp automation. Even after I gave the correct class name and xpath I am unable to understand why its showing noelement exception.
The code should be able to type the contact name and then click on message box and type the message and send.

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain where your error is coming from? Is it the Xpath or class_name? The Xpath you are giving is based off of user input so that is prone to errors...
Many times CLASS_NAME is usually not just one element but multiple, it's usually driver.find_elements

Also you can use implicitly wait or wait for an element to be clickable:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

Or

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, By.CLASS_NAME,"tvf2evcx oq44ahr5 lb5m6g5c svlsagor p2rjqpw5 epia9gcq")))

element.click()
```